How do I extract a matching string from a file using grep sed or awk
I have a file with lines like the following:
34:125 29:215 50:208
33:125 28:215 49:208
32:125 27:215 48:208

I want to extract all the entries for values xx:215.
So the result should be
29:215
28:215
27:215

Please help with the syntax to resolve this. I've tried some grep commands without success.
Thanks!
I've tried using various versions of grep but it didn't give the results I wanted.
Output should be all entries in the file with xx:215.  Getting the numbers in front of the colon is the issue since they vary.

Please show your attempt and explain how it failed.

If you want a solution that searches all 3 columns and/or can sometimes find matches in multiple columns on 1 row or can have no matches in any column in a row then showing an example that only has matches in 1 column where every value matches isn't useful. Similarly for values like xx.2151, x.215 or xxx.215 that you may or may not want to match all or part of. cut -d' ' -f2 would produce the expected output from the sample input you provided, if that's not all you need then [edit] your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output that can be used to test with.

With grep:
grep -oP '\d+:215\b' file
29:215
28:215
27:215

If your grep implementation is missing -P:
grep -o '[0-9]\+:215\b' file



\d+ is the PCRE short for [0-9]+
\b is word boundaries



-o, --only-matching
Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.


-P, --perl-regexp
Interpret PATTERNS as Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCREs).  This option is experimental when combined with the -z (--null-data) option, and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.


With Perl:
perl -lne 'print $& if /\d+:215\b/' file
29:215
28:215
27:215


-o is still nonstandard

@jhnc: *BSD support -o. It's very common. Anyway, added Perl way

it's just a portability warning for future readers. perl -nle 'print for /\d+:215\b/g' ?

A sed version:
<file sed 'y/ /\n/' | sed '/:215/!d'


convert space to newline
discard lines that don't have desired rhs


Perhaps sed 's/ \+/\n/;/^[0-9]\+:215\>/P;D' file

@potong yes, that would avoid the extra exec. I'd use -E now it's standardised: Using \+ in BRE is not guaranteed to work. And \> is not portable.

I tried this and it works great. I was also interested in finding character strings that match xxx:215 and  xxx:218 and found that this works sed 's/ +/\n/;/^[0-9]+:215>/P;/^[0-9]+:218>/P;D' file  . Thanks so much!  The grep solution also works but I haven't got the syntax correct to add additional criteria to that method

Using any POSIX awk and assuming by xx you mean 2 digits, not any 2 characters, this will print every complete (i.e. not a substring) space-separated string that's exactly 2 digits followed by :215 from any column in every row of your input:
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^[0-9]{2}:215$/) print $i}' file
29:215
28:215
27:215

It's always much easier to write a script to match the strings you want than to not match similar strings you don't want so here's some more comprehensive sample input and, I assume, expected output to test with:
$ cat file
34:215 29:215 50:208
33:125 28:2151 A9:215
32:125 7:215 48:208
32:125 27:215 48:215
32:125 127:215 48:208
32:125 $27:215 48:208


$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^[0-9]{2}:215$/) print $i}' file
34:215
29:215
27:215
48:215

Note that it prints the desired xx:215 values from every column of every line as you asked for:

I want to extract all the entries for values xx:215

and, more importantly, it does not print [any part of] the x:215, xxx:215, or xx:215x values which you did not ask for, nor the case where it's xx:215 but one of the xs is not a digit.
You could do the same with GNU grep (for -o and \</\> word boundaries) if your input can't contain undesirable strings like $21:215 (which I included in the input and so is causing the final value below to print):
$ grep -Eo '\<[0-9]{2}:215\>' file
34:215
29:215
27:215
48:215
27:215

but then it's slightly less robust for different undesirable input, less portable and harder to build on if you have additional requirements in future.
